# The wrapper div contains another div in the mark-up but does not seem to contain it when it is rendered in browser. Why?

Tags: html, css, css-position

`.second-one` contains six `<p>` elements and the div `inner-second-one`, which contains `inner-to-inner-second-one`, which contains four `<a>` elements. `background-color:pink` is applied to the `second-one`, and I had anticipated that pink background color will appear everywhere below `first-one`, because all those elements are contained inside the `.second-one`, atleast in the mark-up.

But pink background color only appears as the background of the `<p>` elements inside `.second-one`.

Secondly, when I checked it in the inspector in the web browser, `.second-one` only seems to contain only the `<p>` children of itself, while ignoring the `<inner-second-one>` child (and its children):

[image]

**QUESTIONS:**

1. **Is it because the `<a>` elements have `position:absolute;` set?**
2. **What is the solution?**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first-page {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #81DAF5;
}
.content-other-than-first {
  background-color: grey;
}
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
.first-one {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.second-one {
  background-color: pink;
}
.inner-second-one {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #2EFE9A;
}
.inner-to-inner-second-one {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.one-block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25vw;
  max-height: 400px;
  min-height: 190px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.one-block {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-page">
  <p>.</p>
</div>

<div class="content-other-than-first">
  <div class="full-width first-one">
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width second-one">
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <div class="inner-second-one">
      <div class="inner-to-inner-second-one">
        <a class="one-block" style="top:0; left:0%; width:calc(25% - 20px); background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/HK_TST_Chung_King_%E6%B4%BB%E6%96%B9%E5%95%86%E5%A0%B4_Woodhouse_entrance_escalators.JPG);" href="#"></a>
        <a class="one-block" style="top:0; left:25%; width:calc(25% - 20px); background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/HK_TST_Chung_King_%E6%B4%BB%E6%96%B9%E5%95%86%E5%A0%B4_Woodhouse_Japanese_restaurant_Jika_Udon_open_kitchen_window.JPG);"
        href="#"></a>
        <a class="one-block" style="top:0; left:50%; width:calc(25% - 20px); background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/HK_TST_Chung_King_%E6%B4%BB%E6%96%B9%E5%95%86%E5%A0%B4_Woodhouse_interior_corridor_carpet.JPG);" href="#"></a>
        <a class="one-block" style="top:0; left:75%; width:calc(25% - 20px); background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/HK_TST_Chung_King_%E6%B4%BB%E6%96%B9%E5%95%86%E5%A0%B4_Woodhouse_clothing_shop_JF81_Shibuya_01.JPG);" href="#"></a>
        <a class="one-block" style="top:200px; left:0%; width:calc(25% - 20px); background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Chungking_Mansions_Woodhouse.jpg/800px-Chungking_Mansions_Woodhouse.jpg);" href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (1) You have a different background color specified for your `inner-second-one` which will in any case overwrite your pink color of the parent. (2) The absolute positioning takes the elements out of the flow and hence the container is of no width, which is why you don't see the background. (3) Why are you using absolute positioning anyway???

Comment: @Abhitalks Thank you. "Why are you using absolute positioning anyway???" - it's complicated, it was a part of a big web page, this code just an SSCCE to demonstrate the problem. I can not really avoid absolute positioning.

Comment: @Abhitalks those blocks are added at runtime, and 4 of them are displayed in a row, the fifth one goes to the next line. I don't exactly know how many of them will be added, and what I want is that the background is applied behind them no matter how many of them are added? Can you suggest a solution for that?

Comment: *I can not really avoid absolute positioning* -- in that case there is no solution. If you are open to change the positioning, then it can be easily solved. As per your last comment, the blocks are dynamically added, so it seems you can very much change the CSS.

Comment: See this -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ws121gy6/

Comment: @Abhitalks Thank you very much. I am looking into whether I can get rid of absolute positioning. Did you downvote my question? If so, can you tell me the reason, because without knowing the reason, there really isn't any chance of improvement.

Comment: No I didn't downvote your question, I rather gave you a solution!

Comment: Alright, and thank you for the solution. =)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is `inner-second-one` doesn't have a specified height and so the `background` property doesn't apply. If you change the `height` to `px` or `vh` values then you can see the `background` come through

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion but those blocks are added at runtime, and 4 of them are displayed in a row, the fifth one goes to the next line. I don't exactly know how many of them will be added, and what I want is that the background is applied behind them no matter how many of them are added? What should I do?